# What happened to the data that not belong to any cluster?

Tags: clustering

I try to use trimmed K-means for clustering my data. my data is to cluster countries based on their economy. of course, after the clustering, the outlier will not be included in any cluster.

what happened if the country doesn't belong to any cluster?

Comment: What do you mean, “What happened?” Can you please make your question clearer and more focused?

Comment: do I need to assign them to their own cluster? because I need all the countries but at the same time they are outlier data so I need to get rid of them. It dilemma for me.

Comment: This isn’t a statistics question, then—you’ve done the statistical part of the work. Whatever the end goal of your study is, that’s what governs how you should handle these.